# Deezer SDK for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, deezer

When is Windows Phone 8 (WP8) SDK going to be released?

I have studied and prototyped Deezer API with 30s previews but I would like to get access to streams itself.

I would appreciate early access even to alpha/beta if available... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, non of our SDKs let's you access the full music stream. Our JavaScript/iOS/Android SDK give you the permission to play full tracks - according to user's right.

Are you looking for playing the full track length, or access the Stream to for a specific usage ?

We do not share plans about a "Windows Platform" SDK availability.

Meantime, you can follow my unofficial SDK on GitHub [Deezer Unofficial SDK](https://github.com/cmaneu/deezer-net-api).
It does not includes full song playback, and right now, the list of methods covered are very light, but I'll add support for more methods in the following weeks. You can also raise an issue if you need something, or create a pull request.

Comment: I have already experimented with the unofficial SDK, thanks for it :) I wish to play songs in WP8 without the native music player. Would it be ok to discuss this further directly by email? I prefer not to open our app idea here...

Comment: Sure ! email deezerdevs-at-deezer dot com and cite my name and this StackOverflow thread.